# Permission settings - newform.aspx

Tags: 2013

I can't seem to find/code ways to make my permissions list for particular staff to be only able to enter form data in newform.aspx and not read any information on the list itself.

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

In my experience, this is where SharePoint's permission levels can save the day. However when creating custom permission levels through the GUI, you can't customize them to the extent necessary to accomplish this.

PowerShell to the rescue! You can use the following snippet to create a custom permission level - AddOnlyNoRead - and assign it to the applicable users/groups. This will allow users to add items, but not read, edit or delete them.

```
Add-PSSnapin microsoft.sharepoint.powershell
$url = "http://<site>"
$web = Get-SPWeb -Identity $url
$addOnlyNoReadRole = New-Object "Microsoft.SharePoint.SPRoleDefinition"
$addOnlyNoReadRole.Name = "AddOnlyNoRead"
$addOnlyNoReadRole.Description = "This group can add items, but cannot view, delete or edit items"
$addOnlyNoReadRole.BasePermissions = "AddListItems,ViewPages,ViewFormPages,Open"
$web.RoleDefinitions.Add($addOnlyNoReadRole)
```

Be sure to update the $url variable to your site collection URL.

Hope this helps!